# How open a C++ .SLN project in xamarin studio on Mac?

Tags: c++, xamarin, xamarin-studio, solution

I have a .sln file that i want to open in Xamarin studio, the problem is that this file is  in c ++, and when i open the project this message appear : "Xamarin studio don't allow this type of project"

I update Xamarin studio to version 6 and I think in previous versions i could work not only on projects with C # but also in c and c ++, I think I need to add a supplement to Xamarin studio

so how can i open a C ++ solution in Xamarin studio on Mac? or if this is impossible, what other option i have?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that support for C++ projects has been removed.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/76210/c-c-project-templates-missing-from-xamarin-studio

Answer (score -1):

If I am correct, *.sln files are generated and used only by Microsoft's Visual Studio, they might not be compatible with other IDEs.

You might be lucky and the project uses some Build generator like CMAKE or Premake. If this is the case, you can use these tools to generate the correct project file for Xamarin. Consider reading the tool documentation to get more information about this.

If this is not the case, then you will have to manually recreate your Build System in Xamarin, in a new blank project file created inside it. This involves manually copying source files and whatnot that was part of your codebase and matching as close as possible your original Visual Studio build options and flags. Some trial and error will be necessary. It might also be humanly impossible if the project is too complex or uses custom build steps.

You can easily verify that your Xamarin installation has C++ support by trying to create inside it a C++ project and compiling a traditional Hello World. I think it is currently not supported and what you remember is really MonoDevelop, the previous IDE used by Xamarin the Company. That one does support C++, but I'm not sure of its current status or if support is available.

Comment: Not correct. XS can open .sln files the same way as VS

Comment: @xleon well, always learning something new :D is the XML schema the same or similar in both IDEs?

Comment: It´s mostly the same, except some edge cases are not supported by XS (mostlly bugs). The opposite works as well, you can create the solution with XS and then open it with VS